# Is it possible to construct a sample space where $A$ and $B$ are independent events and $P(A) = P(B) = 0.5$?

Tags: probability

Repeating the question from the title

> Is it possible to construct a sample space where $A$ and $B$ are independent events and $P(A) = P(B) = 0.5$?

My attempts so far:

For the sample space with cardinality of less than $3$, it is clearly not possible.

It is also not possible if we have three outcomes. We can show it by contradiction:

Let $\Omega = \{s_1,s_2,s_3\}$. We know that events are independent iff they are joint. So WLOG, we can take $A = \{s_1, s_2\}$, $B = \{s_2, s_3\}$ and suppose $A,B$ are independent with $P(A) = 0.5$ and $P(B) = 0.5$. Then we must have $P(A)P(B) = P(\{s_2\}) = 0.25$, implying that $P(\{s_1\}) = P(\{s_3\}) = 0.25$, but then $P(\{s_1\}) + P(\{s_2\}) + P(\{s_3\}) ≠1$, thus normalization axiom fails.

I've also attempted to show that it is not possible for the sample space with $4$ outcomes. (but I wont post it here, because I am not confident that it is accurate)

Thus, so far I believe that is not possible to have a sample space with aforementioned conditions being satisfied. **So can we construct such sample space?**

Comment: How about 2 coin flips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sample space $\Omega=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ the uniform probability measure on $\Omega$.
Consider $A=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ and $B=\{(0,1),(1,1)\}$, then $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(B)=\frac{1}{2}$ and
$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = \mathbb{P}(\{ (1,1) \}) = \frac{1}{4} = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$$